# HTML Button Not Taking Up Full Width of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I have an area on my website where events are listed. I have a parent div for the container and a div for each event section. When the user hovers over the section, an edit and delete button pops up on the left:

[image]

The problem is the button isn't taking up the full width of the div, but only is as long as the text is. I know other questions have been asked, but none of the answers, such as adding `box-sizing: border-box`, work for me.

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 inline mb-4">  
    <h3 class="ml-2">Reminders:</h3>
    <div class="events-content-section ml-2">
        {% for reminder in reminders %}   
            <div class="mb-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                <ul class="reminderUl">
                    <li>
                        <span class="reminderSpan">
                            <button type="button" class="update-reminder btn btn-info" data-id="{% url 'update-reminder' reminder.pk %}"> 
                                <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>   
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="reminderSpan">
                            <button type="button" class="delete-reminder btn btn-danger" data-id="{% url 'delete-reminder' reminder.pk %}">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>    
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <button class="view-reminder btn btn-light" data-id="{% url 'view-reminder' reminder.pk %}">   
                            <h4>{{ reminder.title }}</h4>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        {% endfor %}    
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Being that you're already using Bootstrap I recommend using the [`btn-block`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons) class.

Comment: I added the class to the button that displays the title, but the button doesn't span the entire page and the buttons get pushed up. https://imgur.com/a/rbvrGjr

Comment: It seems like the container is playing a role here as well. Without your CSS and ideally an isolated demo with static data as filler it's very difficult to help.

Comment: You can use Python Fiddle to set it up: http://pythonfiddle.com/django/

Comment: I didn't know how to use python fiddle, but I put the basics of my project here: https://repl.it/repls/FancySmoggyRegister. Also, I don't know if this matters, but I didn't put any menus in thats on my test site.

Comment: So how big do you want the buttons to be? You say you want them to take up the parents width (https://repl.it/repls/PlayfulAttractiveProtools) but I assume that's not what you mean. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: I want the buttons to be the size of the overall reminders div, like this: https://imgur.com/a/MWzx09h. When the user hovers over the button it should compress to show the menu options on the left. But when I added the btn-block, it just shifted the menu on top of the button, and the button doesn't span the whole div.